# Extracting data from vector B based on values in vector A

Tags: r

R programming language question:

I have two vectors of identical size, A and B, holding integer values. How do I make a third vector C consisting of values from B based on some criteria of vector A?

As an example, if vector A contained 0s and 1s and vector B has integers from 1-100, how do I make a new vector C consisting of vector B values when the corresponding vector A value is 1?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your condition. 
In your example, if you want the vector C to be of same lenth of A and B, and 0 when A is 0, the value of B where A is 1, then you just have to do `C=A*B`, which will multiply element by element.
Otherwise, if you want to keep only values of B where A is 1 (then C will be a smaller vector), you can do `C=B[A==1]`. 
This will keep only values of B where A respect the given condition (==1 here).

Comment: If have two vectors, A and B (identical lengths), and I want to form a third vector C of the same length and want C to consist of values of A when B == 2 (or some condition) and 0 otherwise.